# Azure Mobile Services: no data tab

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to create a simple table in Azure Mobile Services so that my c# Windows Phone App can utilize a high score table. However, though it appears in every example I find online, there is no "Data" tab inside my mobile service I created on Azure where I can create that table. They removed it or something, but there is no documentation whatsoever. Anyone know what's going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You probably chose to use a .NET backend (as opposed to JavaScript).  When you do so, the DATA and API tabs are not visible in the portal.  This is because both your data access and custom API's are part of your Visual Studio solution and have to be deployed from there.  If you want to use the Javascript backend where you create your tables, APIs, and edit their scripts in the portal, you'll need to create a new Mobile Service and choose Javascript as the backend.

Comment: Thank you! I'm amazed that either A) this was not clearly explained anywhere or B) I didn't see where it was clearly explained.

Comment: It is rather option A. For example: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-phone-get-started-data/ - windows phone, .NET backend and what we can see in 'Add a new table to the mobile service' chapter? I find it very confusing.

Comment: If you look at the top of that page, you'll see there are links for the .NET Backend and JavaScript Backend walkthroughs.  The .NET one doesn't mention the data tab.  That said, this is definitely something we should highlight as a difference.....or add the data tab into the .NET backend if possible.  Thanks for the feedback on this needing to be clearer, I'll try to make that happen.

Comment: It seems to me that the Data tab might have been available for Mobile Services with a .NET backend at some point. I've found a bunch of apparently outdated and confusing documentation and blogs which refer to the Data tab for .NET backends.

Comment: Thanks - and if, like me, you'd been scratching your head for hours following the Azure tutorial "Add push notifications to your Mobile Services app" you may have re-visited the page and not noticed that that the "Backend" drop down list selection right at the top of the tutorial had flicked back to 'JavaScript' for the back-end.

Comment: So, how do I set permissions if I cannot see Data tab? This article below says use the data tab. Or should I just choose JS as back-end? Does it change how I access the DB if I change it to JS back-end? http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started-users/#permissions

Comment: Strider, if you look at that article, go to the top where there is a drop down for BACKEND.  Select .NET and it will explain how you use code attributes in the .NET backend to set your permissions.

Comment: So it means that we can only browse the database via VS when we use .net backend? is it still the case in 2016 ? :)

Comment: You can use VS or SQL Management Studio or the Silverlight SQL tool (if that is still around) to view data in the DB.  You still can't see that data in the portal AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

When you first create a mobile service, you won't have [**any data in the**] data tab. The easiest way to get started is to choose one of the sample app templates (iOS, Android, Windows Phone, Windows 8, HTML, Xamarin, PhoneGap). You should see an option then, to download the client app. There should also be an option to set up a default bit of data (the todoitem table). Once this is done, you should see the Data tab.

This isn't the only way to create data, but it's the simplest, especially when first starting out.

Comment: This is not accurate.  The DATA tab will always show up for the JavaScript backend but will never (currently) show up for the .NET backend.  Going through the quick start template app is not necessary.

Comment: Ok, yes, technically speaking, the tab *exists* - as in, it can be seen. But... there is no actual data. Edited my answer to clarify that.